# Excel - update column B y/n if it is first appearance of text in column A

Tags: excel-formula

I have:
column A "email" containing email address
column B "new email?" containing y or n.

In need to program the sheet to add y to column B, only if this the the first appearance of that email in column A. Otherwise, column B value for that email row will be n
example:

```
email         new_email?
aaa@zz.com    y
aaa@zz.com    n
bbb@zz.com    y
aaa@zz.com    n
bbb@zz.com    n
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming your data starts in row 2): Use the function "MATCH" in column B referencing on the range A$2:A2 with lookup value A3 in B3 and the copy it down. If A2 is not in A$2:A2 it will return #NA. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx

Then use an IFNA to get the Y/N. (Note that B2 is always "Y"). The third argument of MATCH has be set to "exact match" (i.e. 0).

So:

- in B3 you have =IFNA(MATCH(A3,A$2:A2,0),"N","Y"))
- in B4 you have =IFNA(MATCH(A4,A$2:A3,0),"N","Y"))

etc

Comment: Hi Christain & thanks. When I copied & pasted the formula you sent as is in B3 & B34. However, it doesn't show the formula, but only shows the text ... ie  ... =IFNA(MATCH(A4,A$2:A3,0),"N","Y"))

Comment: Sorry Christian, I'm using Excel 2010

Comment: IFNA requires Excel 2013. Otherwise use IFERROR http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx